# How to put wide pictures on a slide?

Tags: beamer, graphics

I would like to put wide figures (or some figures with overall wider than the standard textwidth) centered on a slide. I think the easiest way to change the textwidth on that specific slide, isn't it? How to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Don't change the textwidth, just hide the width of the image.

```
\begin{center}
\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics{...}}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Why don't we need to add `[c]` after `[0pt]`?

Comment: I see, `[c]` is the default.